# How to do inner construct for Frame() with super()?

Tags: java, linux, swing, user-interface, awt

How can i do a initialization for the Frame() while its getting used inside the super()? Like following in a valid way, so that the Frame and all super related has a color RED?

Note: Basically the right red box should not show because Color(r,g,b,ALPHA);

[image]

```
public class 999 extends Window 
{
  private JLabel label;
  private JButton button;
  private static final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
  private static final Canvas canvas0 = new Canvas();
  private JLayeredPane layers;

  public 999() 
  {
        super(new Frame());
        // Please make this **TRANSPARENT**
        getOwner().setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 0) ); 

        layers = new JLayeredPane();
        button = new JButton("close");

        this.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());     

        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button.setSize(200,200);
        button.setLocation(0,20);
        this.add("North", button);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setOpaque(false); // transparent
        p.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 0) ); // transparent

        p.setSize(300, 200);
        p.setLocation(0, 0);
        p.add(new JButton("Test"));
        layers.add(p, new Integer(1));
        layers.setSize(400,300);
        layers.setLocation(400,50);

        layers.setOpaque(false); // transparent
        layers.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 0) ); // transparent
        this.add("North", layers);

        canvas.setSize(800,800);
        this.add("North",canvas);
        //AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.2f); // Error in Linux

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      Window j = new 999();
      j.setVisible(true);
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure if 999 is a valid name for a class. I don't know java though...

Comment: Because a [class name](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1) is an [idenitifier](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8), "999" is not a valid name.

Comment: 1) Don't mix Swing with AWT.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Anbdrew Thompson: What do you mean by Swing/AWT mix? Specially the Canvas? (that is the culprit in my case).

Comment: Is it Swing', 'AWT' or 'mix' that you do not understand?  Any chance of seeing that SSCCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is really odd.  Create the frame elsewhere and set the values you want before you give it to this object.  Or just make this call in your constructor:

```
 getOwner().setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 255) );
```

Comment: This is giving error: super(new Frame(){ getOwner().setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 255) ); });

Comment: No, in the constructor of the 999 class.

Comment: please see above, its not working, i have RED background instead of transparent.